# How to use NSAttributedStrings in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I would like to have a label with an attributed string that changes dynamically at runtime. Something like this

[image]

Is there a better way to dynamically change the price value without hardcoding the attributed keys dictionaries and manually building the `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: What is the issue in this ?

Comment: There is no specific issue, was just looking for a better way to avoid NSAttributedStringKey hardcoding and I think Efraim's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to approach Attributed Strings on iOS is by using the built-in Attributed Text editor in the interface builder and avoid uneccessary hardcoding NSAtrributedStringKeys in your source files.

You can later dynamically replace  placehoderls at runtime by using this extension:

```swift
extension NSAttributedString {
    func replacing(placeholder:String, with valueString:String) -> NSAttributedString {

        if let range = self.string.range(of:placeholder) {
            let nsRange = NSRange(range,in:valueString)
            let mutableText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
            mutableText.replaceCharacters(in: nsRange, with: valueString)
            return mutableText as NSAttributedString
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Add a storyboard label with attributed text looking like this.

[image]

Then you simply update the value each time you need like this:

```swift
label.attributedText = initalAttributedString.replacing(placeholder: "<price>", with: newValue)
```

Make sure to save into initalAttributedString the original value.

You can better understand this approach by reading this article:
https://medium.com/mobile-appetite/text-attributes-on-ios-the-effortless-approach-ff086588173e

Comment: Excellent answer. A caution, though, and paraphrasing the docs: "The new characters inherit the attributes of the first replaced character from the target range." This means that if the string in the target range has different attributes over the range, those differences will be lost.

Comment: So, for example, if you tried to replace "Price: 32" with "Price: 25" The bold red attributes on the number would be lost and the number would have the same text attributes as the word "Price" at the beginning of the original attributed string. In order to preserve the attributes of the starting string you have to replace substrings that have different attributes piecewise.

Comment: You can always keep an original copy of the mock, which would be something like this Price: <price> (NET VALUE) and use label.attributedText = label.attributedText?.replacing(placeholder: "<price>", with: newValue). Please read my medium article on this one for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

May not know, this is what you're looking for but will solve your problem.

You may use labels for each and update amount easily without touching attributed string.

[image]

Here is result:

[image]

Sample code, I've tried for this demo:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblAmount: UILabel!
func pricelabel() -> Void {
    var amount = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        amount += 10
        self.lblAmount.text = "\(amount)"
    }.fire()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But i think it's way easier to handle a single Label rather than having 3 different ones. Building the attributed text from the interface builder editor seems way easier and cleaner.